# Canvas crashes Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, canvas

I am working on a web experience that allows you scrub through stills by scrolling back and forth on browser. 
The problem I am running into is that Chrome crashes occassionally as I am scrolling.
This does not crash in Firefox, so I am assuming I am doing something that Chrome doesn't like. Any ideas?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

"use strict";

//loading array function
function preLoad(file, total_array, arrayme, type){
    for(var i = 1; i < total_array; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      var file_entry = file + i +type;
      console.log(file_entry);
      img.src = file_entry;
      arrayme.push(img);
    }
}

var images = new Array();
var size = 899;
var filename = 'http://t-mrkt.com/Lab/media/MASTER_COMP_';
var file_type =".png";

preLoad(filename,size,images,file_type);

var canv = document.getElementById('background');
var context = canv.getContext('2d');

$(canv)
    .width($(window).width())
    .height($(window).height());

var currentLocation = 0;
//variable for 1/4 proportion 
var arr = Math.floor(images.length/4);

var lastScroll = 0;
var maxScrollLeft = document.getElementById('all').scrollWidth - 
                    document.getElementById('all').clientWidth;

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var window_loc = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if (window_loc > lastScroll) {
        if (window_loc - lastScroll < 10) {
            currentLocation += 1;
        }
        if (window_loc - lastScroll > 10) {
            currentLocation += 10;
        }          
    }

    if (window_loc < lastScroll) {
        if (window_loc - lastScroll > -10) {
            currentLocation -= 1;
        }
        if (window_loc -lastScroll < -10) {
            currentLocation -= 10;  
        }
    }

    if (currentLocation < 0) {
        currentLocation = 0;
        window_loc = $('body').scrollLeft(0);
        console.log("less than zero");
    }

    if (currentLocation > images.length-1) {
        currentLocation = images.length-1;
        window_loc = $('body').scrollLeft(maxScrollLeft);
        console.log("more than full length");
    }

    //updating value to latest 
    lastScroll = window_loc;
    setImage(currentLocation);

});

function setImage(newLocation) {
    context.drawImage(images[newLocation], 0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    console.log(images.length + "length of images");
}

});
```

Comment: Do you know roughly at what part it's crashing? *Edit*: I'm not sure what your HTML setup is like but [this seems to work just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/qUb8L/)

Comment: Typically going back and forth will trigger it. Try as I may, I cannot get it to happen in Firefox. Same issue happens in Canary as well, whether or not I am using strict.

Comment: Setup a jsfiddle then because I could not recreate it in mine.

Comment: Thanks. I just added most of the code to http://jsfiddle.net/PTH79/

Comment: Scrolling back and forth, and going to end and then back crashes my chrome browser Version 36.0.1985.125

Comment: It probably has to do with your graphics drivers and how much you have going on. I get some visual tearing but not a crash. For example, some people's browsers crash when running [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/multiple-drawimage-vs-pattern) and that seemed to be because of graphics drivers/cards.

Comment: Yes! you are right. I tried it with a few different machines and on some it didn't crash. I wonder though, how these guys got theirs to work without crashing cross machine/gpu http://discover.store.sony.com/be-moved/ I am using a different event, since this is to be shown on a touch screen so I cannot use mouse, but have to use scroll and computing the delta manually between last position and current. Any suggestions to optimize?

Comment: In short, reduce the size of your drawing areas. Rather than doing one large canvas, try breaking it in to 3 or so regions. Then you can unload the canvas which isn't visible when it's outside of the visible region and reduce the load on the GPU.